# Will setting Rails model attributes with the same value make changed? return true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, seeding

I'm looking to make my `db:seed` task a little more dynamic by allowing certain entries in my application to be created or updated (or nothing at all) based on the values of in `db/seeds.rb` and the current state of the backend database. I'm also looking to simplify the functions that carry this logic out.

I'd like to avoid this:

```
def create_or_update_config(key, value)

  ...

  if config_entry.value != value
    config_entry.value
  end

  if config_entry.changed?
    config_entry.save
  end

  ...

end
```

And instead have something simplistic:

```
def create_or_update_config(key, value)

  ...

  config_entry.value = value

  if config_entry.changed?
    config_entry.save
  end

  ...

end
```

Is ActiveRecord smart enough to know if attribute values have changed even if they've been set (with the same value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. ActiveRecord's `changed?` method will return true only if there were mutations since the last save. From an example using my own app's console (Rails 5.1.6):

```
irb(main):013:0> config.value
=> "http://localhost:3100"
irb(main):014:0> config.value = "http://localhost:3100"
=> "http://localhost:3100"
irb(main):015:0> config.changed?
=> false
irb(main):016:0> config.value = "anything else"
=> "anything else"
irb(main):017:0> config.changed?
=> true
```